# Apache Rewrite for Entire Subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How would I go about rewriting :

```html
proxmox.example.com
```

to

```
example.com/forward/?url=proxmox.example.com
```

- I am trying to do this on Ubuntu with Apache
- Please let me know what Apache plugins are used.
- Will this rewrite go into my VirtualHosts file? (/etc/apache2/sites-available)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need a vhost for that. It can be put in the main Apache config.
Put this in your config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(proxmox.(example.com))$
RewriteRule .* http://%2/forward/?url=%1 [R,L]
```

Use [P,L] instead of 'R' if you want to mask/hide the rewrite from the user. Otherwise stay with 'P'.

Also I used two nested brackets to retrieve example.com (value is stored in %2) and use that instead of a static 'example.com' in the second line. But if you prefer a 'clearer' (=easier to read) rule, use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(proxmox.example.com)$
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/forward/?url=%1 [R,L]
```

Hope it helped. Let us know if it did, and even more so, if it didn't so we can help furthermore :)

Comment: You are a god! This is exactly what I had in mind! Thank you for sharing information regarding the [P,L] and R stuff too!